# Anonymous and Secure File Uploading

Tags: web-apps, security, google-drive, cloud

I help run a community group and need suggestions on an anonymous and secure file upload website. This group helps people deal with sensitive personal issues. I'd like a free option and limited storage will work.

We currently use Google Docs but I don't like it that when I log into the website's dashboard, files (like .docx files) have a thumbnail preview of the text. Also when I view a file on Google Docs the email addresses of whoever the file is shared with are viewed (like emily@example.com).

Instead when I log into this anonymous and secure file upload website I don't want it to display any personal information (like an email) or a document preview thumbnail in the website's UI. I could then view a Word doc or PDF by downloading it to my computer and opening it up. **I don't care about the option to anonymous share files with people.**

Let me know if you have good suggestions.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [SecureDrop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecureDrop)?

Comment: Since I work with people who are mostly not web devs, I was wondering if there's a service on the web that will work and that is free for a little bit of web storage. 

For example would Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/) work, where when I log in I won't be able to see the email address of the profile I'm logged in with and there will be no previous of documents that show thumbnails? I can make up an anonymous profile alias name in Dropbox.

Comment: Huh? Those people can just use the client (e.g. Tor-Browser), no need for being a web dev. And no, I wouldn't trust any cloud provider if it comes to sensitive data – which is what you're asking about. Using SecureDrop, people can just "drop" files into your "inbox" (at least that's how I understood it). I must admit I haven't dug into it very deep; a good starting point [would be here](https://github.com/freedomofpress/securedrop#how-to-use-securedrop). Also [see here](https://www.theguardian.com/securedrop) for an example.